# User ID attribute in JWT token to the backend WSO2 APIM

Tags: jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm having trouble implementing the following use case. I need to pass the User ID claim to the backend. I've enabled enable_outbound_auth_header so that the token I get from the application arrives to the backend. I've managed to add the User ID to this token. I want to use JWT grant, Code grant, client credentials grant and APIKey. However, User ID is only added to the token on code and JWT grants. The way I did it was using OIDC scopes.I've seen in docs that I can use apim.jwt to pass enduser attributes, however I haven't managed to pass User ID. Is there any way to achieve this? (without custom generators)

In the case I have to implement a custom token generation I'm wondering which one to
implement. I've seen that there are many possibilities. Should I implement a token generator? Will this one work for apiKey token? I think there are at least four possible toke generators (gateway token generator, jwt token generator, oauth token generator and oidc token generator. Which one or how many should I implement?

Comment: Can you share the API Manager version that you are using? and how you managed to get the User ID in both JWT Grant and Code Grant Tokens? Meantime, You can also write a custom JWT Generator by referring to [Docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-jwt/#jwt-self-contained-access-tokens). This is applicable to the Self-Contained Access Tokens (not for API Key), and this implementation will be executed to generate the Backend JWT Token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing two custom token generators. I just inherited from the default class implementation for each generator and added the userId claim. Then I added them in the deployment.toml

For the apikey generator (extended DefaultApiKeyGenerator) simply added

```
[apim.devportal]
url = "https://localhost:9443/devportal"
api_key_generator_impl = "com.apikeygenerator.CustomAPIKeyGenerator"
```

The other one I implemented was the oauth token generator (extended JWTTokenIssuer). Adding this one to the configuration using

```
[[oauth.extensions.token_types]]
name = "JWT"
issuer = "com.oauthjwtgenerator.CustomOauthJWTGenerator"
```